# SQLite: Join 2 columns from 2 seperate databases together

Tags: sqlite

How do I join 2 tables from different database in SQLite? I've added both databases to the SQL studio manager.

I want to join these 2 columns:

- "SpiceWorks_Prod.db"."Devices".Name
- "temp"."Licenses".name

Where "spiceworks_prod.db" is the database and 
"Devices" is the column name and 
".name" is the field name.

Here's the script i have so far :

```
SELECT "Licenses".name
FROM "temp"."Licenses"
JOIN "SpiceWorks_Prod.db"."Devices"
ON "Licenses".name="Devices".Name
```

The error i receive is  "Error while executing query: Invalid database name: SpiceWorks_Prod.db"

Comment: You probably already opened `"SpiceWorks_Prod.db"`, so it should be `main`.

Comment: Execute `PRAGMA database_list;` to get a list of database names.

Comment: Its not. ive found a work around by importing a table into the database so the source and destination are in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Open spiceworks in the normal way then ATTACH the temp database. The JOIN will work then as long as you fulyy qualify the database names.

Comment: Its not. ive found a work around by importing a table into the database so the source and destination are in the same table.